# Is PlatformKeyCode the same across different countries (keyboards)?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyevent

the question is simple and requires even simpler answer (yes or no :) )
Is PlatformKeyCode the same across different countries (and therefore different keyboards layouts)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

From the [KeyEventArgs.PlatformKeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.platformkeycode%28VS.95%29.aspx) documentation:

> Gets an integer value that represents
>   the key that is pressed or released
>   (depending on which event is raised).
>   **This value is the nonportable key
>   code, which is operating
>   system–specific.**

This looks like a scan code, which also depends on the keyboard layout.

Comment: Many thanks, I've read the definition of platformKeyCode before, but it doesn't mention anything about internationalization. Your comment made it a little bit clearer.